# .htaccess requires extra '../' on src files

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, relative-path

I am trying to turn

```
Topics?t=a
```

Into

```
Topics/a
```

For that purpose i wrote this htaccess code

```
RewriteRule ^Topics/([0-9a-zA-Z]+) Topics.php?t=$1 [NC,L]
```

And now when url is `Topics/a` it requires extra '../' on src files like css or javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Requirement to add an extra `../` is due to the fact that you're using **relative paths** in your css/js/images.

The new pretty URL in use is this:

```
Topics/a
```

If you're including css as `href=style.css` then it will try to find it as `/Topics/style.css`.

When using `../` it will correctly find css as `/Topics/../style.css` that translates to `/style.css`.

Note that instead of `../` you can add a `/` before your `relative path` to make it as:

```
href=/style.css
```

**Alternatively** You can add this just below `<head>` section of your page's HTML:

```
<base href="/" />
```

so that every **relative URL** is resolved from that base URL and not from the current page's URL.